# calling methods for string prototype

Tags: javascript, methods

can someone explain why executing this below result in getting toUpperCase function?

("string")["toUpperCase"]

> > function toUpperCase()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: I found the question interesting, so I will try to provide a detailed answer.

Also, allow me to change your example to:

```
("hello")["toUpperCase"]
```

as the use of "*string*" could mislead programming newcomers (e.g. "string" is a string).

---

## SHORT ANSWER:

Because `("hello")` gets temporary converted to a String object whose property `["toUpperCase"]` has a reference to a Function instance. When you do:

```
console.log( ("hello")["toUpperCase"] );
```

you are accessing the value of that property, i.e., a reference to the `toUpperCase` function.

---

## LONG ANSWER:

Let's break `("hello")["toUpperCase"]` into pieces:

- `("hello")` evaluates as a *string literal* (a *primitive* data type).
- `["toUpperCase"]` access a method (a property containing a *function definition*).

---

### `("hello")`

We keep on breaking down:

`"hello"` is, undoubtedly, a string literal:

```
console.log( typeof "hello" ); // Logs "string"
```

When we wrap it in parentheses ([grouping operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping)) it becomes a *parenthesized expression*. As you can read in the [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-grouping-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

> ParenthesizedExpression : ( Expression )
>
> Return the result of evaluating Expression. This may be of type Reference.

It means that a parenthesized expression evaluates to the value of the expression within the parentheses. As result of it:

```
console.log( "hello" === ("hello") ); // Logs "true"
console.log( typeof ("hello") ); // Logs "string"
```

So we can conclude that `("hello")` evaluates as a *string literal*.

---

### `["toUpperCase"]`

As you can read in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors), the *bracket notation* is as valid as the *dot notation* when accessing object's properties:

> Property accessors provide access to an object's properties by using
>   the dot notation or the bracket notation.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> object.property
> object["property"]
> ```

Now, maybe you are wondering why I talk about properties if [`toUpperCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) is a method. If you keep on reading the same link above:

> One can think of an object as an associative array (a.k.a. map,
>   dictionary, hash, lookup table). The keys in this array are the names
>   of the object's properties. It's typical when speaking of an object's
>   properties to make a distinction between properties and methods.
>   However, the property/method distinction is little more than a
>   convention. A method is simply a property that can be called, for
>   example if it has a reference to a Function instance as its value.

Actually, the ECMAScript specification [defines *method*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.27) as "function that is the value of a property".

So we can conclude that `["toUpperCase"]` is a property accessor (provide access to an object's property).

---

### `("hello")["toUpperCase"]` together again

We have seen that `("hello")["toUpperCase"]` is equivalent to `"hello".toUpperCase`, actually:

```
console.log( ("hello")["toUpperCase"] === "hello".toUpperCase ); // Logs "true"
```

But, why is this working? `"hello"` is not an *object*! it is a *string literal* (a *primitive*)!

That is completely right:

```
console.log( typeof "hello" ); // Logs "string"
console.log( typeof new String("hello") );  // Logs "object"
```

but JavaScript will coerce that literal into an object for you, so you can use the `toUpperCase` method. As you can read in the definition for the *String global object* in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String):

> String literals (denoted by double or single quotes) and strings
>   returned from String calls in a non-constructor context (i.e., without
>   using the new keyword) are primitive strings. JavaScript automatically
>   converts primitives to String objects, so that it's possible to use
>   String object methods for primitive strings. In contexts where a
>   method is to be invoked on a primitive string or a property lookup
>   occurs, JavaScript will automatically wrap the string primitive and
>   call the method or perform the property lookup.

That object will be discarded afterwards ([MDN - Grammar and types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types)):

> You can call any of the methods of the String object on a string
>   literal value—JavaScript automatically converts the string literal to
>   a temporary String object, calls the method, then discards the
>   temporary String object.

So we can conclude that `("hello")["toUpperCase"]` is accessing the `toUpperCase` method/property from the (temporary) String object "hello".

---

### So, why am I getting a function?

Because that is what is inside the object's property: it is the *value* of the property. It is said that *functions* in JavaScript are "first class citizens", meaning that you can pass them around like any other piece of data. You can do things like this:

```
var foo = new String( "I am foo" );
foo.upperCase = ("hello")["toUpperCase"];   
console.log( foo.upperCase() ); // Logs "I AM FOO"
```

If what you want is to invoke the method, you need to use the *function call operator* `()`.

```
console.log( ("hello")["toUpperCase"]() ); // Logs "HELLO"
```